# Powershell - automatically add password into copy-item code

Tags: powershell

Good day all,

I am running a line of code to download agent logs from multiple servers remotely but I am running into a delay with the current line of code I am working with.

```
copy-item -path C:\Agent.txt -destination c:\Local\ -fromSession (new-PSSession SERVERNAME -credential DOMAIN\USERNAME -UseSSL -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck))
```

This will prompt for credentials with the `DOMAIN\USERNAME` already filled in. What I am hoping to do is for it to begin the download immediately without me having to type in a password for each one.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal place to use variables. You are being prompted each time because you instructed it to do so. If you break it up and store the credentials in a variable, then you won't keep getting prompted.

```
$session = new-PSSession SERVERNAME -credential DOMAIN\USERNAME -UseSSL -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck)
copy-item -path C:\Agent.txt -destination c:\Local\ -fromSession $session
```

You may also consider splatting to make the code easier to read and maintain. This may not be the best demonstration, however I thought it was worth mentioning.

```
$sessopt = @{
    ComputerName  = 'SERVERNAME'
    Credential    = 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'
    UseSSL        = $true
    SessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck
}

$session = New-PSSession @sessopt

$copyopt = @{
    Path        = 'C:\Agent.txt'
    Destination = 'C:\Local\'
    FromSession = $session
}

Copy-Item @copyopt
```